# Problema al descartar tablas con registros vacios PL/SQL

Tags: oracle-11g, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper

Muy buenas, he realizado un procedimiento en PL que filtra tablas cuyas columnas coincidan o contengan la palabra que reciba de un parámetro y genere un fichero .CSV, la cuestión es que he pensado en, además, descartar aquellas tablas que no contengan ningún registro. ¿Cómo podría realizar el descarte al recorrer el cursor? (Abajo el código)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXPORTCOLUMNSDATA
    ( V_REGSEARCH IN VARCHAR2, V_DIRECTORY OUT VARCHAR2 ) IS

    V_TABLE ALL_TAB_COLUMNS.TABLE_NAME%TYPE;
    V_COLUMN VARCHAR2(5000);
    V_FILE  UTL_FILE.FILE_TYPE;

    CURSOR REGFILTER IS 
        SELECT co.TABLE_NAME, co.COLUMN_NAME
        FROM ALL_TAB_COLUMNS co
        WHERE REGEXP_LIKE (co.COLUMN_NAME, V_REGSEARCH)
        ORDER BY co.TABLE_NAME asc;

BEGIN
    SELECT DIRECTORY_PATH INTO V_DIRECTORY FROM ALL_DIRECTORIES WHERE DIRECTORY_NAME = 'EXTRACTION';

/*Creates the file and sets it's name*/
V_FILE := UTL_FILE.FOPEN('EXTRACTION','ColumnData_'|| To_char(Sysdate, 'DD-MM_YY')||'.CSV','W'); 
/*Header*/
UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(V_FILE,'TABLE:'||';'||'COLUMNS:');
V_TABLE := NULL;
V_COLUMN := NULL;

FOR reg IN REGFILTER
    LOOP
        IF(V_TABLE = reg.TABLE_NAME) THEN
            V_COLUMN := V_COLUMN || '  ' || reg.COLUMN_NAME;
        ELSE
            V_TABLE := reg.TABLE_NAME;
            V_COLUMN := reg.COLUMN_NAME;
            UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(V_FILE, V_TABLE||';'|| V_COLUMN); --Writes the data.
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

UTL_FILE.FCLOSE(V_FILE);

/*Error-Handling*/

END EXPORTCOLUMNSDATA;
```

ACTUALIZACIÓN:

Fragmento de código probado:

```
-- create/replace procedure

--v_table
--v_column
V_SELECT VARCHAR2(500);
V_CHECK NUMBER(1);
--v_file
 --declare cursor

BEGIN
--Set directory + file & initialise table, column null

FOR reg IN REGFILTER
    LOOP
        IF(V_TABLE = reg.TABLE_NAME) THEN
            V_SELECT := 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM '|| V_TABLE ||' WHERE ROWNUM = 1';
            begin 
            EXECUTE IMMEDIATE V_SELECT INTO V_CHECK;
            exception
                when others then
                v_check := 0;
            end;
            IF (V_CHECK = 1) THEN
                V_COLUMN := V_COLUMN || '  ' || reg.COLUMN_NAME;
            END IF;
        ELSE
            V_TABLE := reg.TABLE_NAME;
            V_COLUMN := reg.COLUMN_NAME;
            UTL_FILE.PUT_LINE(V_FILE, V_TABLE||';'|| V_COLUMN); --Writes the data.
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

-- close file + exceptions

END EXPORTCOLUMNSDATA;
```

Comment: Si REGFILTER tiene todas las tablas a tratar, deberás hacer una consulta en el bucle para cada una de ellas en la que saques el número de registros que hay o, quizás más eficiente, obtener el primero. Si el recuento te devuelve 0 o la lectura del primero no devuelve ningún registro, entonces esa tabla te la puedes saltar

Comment: Si no he comprendido mal, te refieres a esto: SELECT COUNT(*) INTO X FROM V_TABLE WHERE ROWNUM = 1 y después comprobar si X vale 0, ¿Me equivoco?

Comment: Podría valer, sí

Comment: Probé a validar el valor de X dentro del If y no ha funcionado, también he probado con SQL dinámico. ¿Alguna otra sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Puedes poner la sql que pruebes en el post para poder comprobarla?

Comment: Ahí lo tienes, he intentado con la SQL dinámica ver si existen registros en la tabla y en función de eso, no recoger las columnas.

Comment: Quita lo del WHERE ROWNUM = 1 aunque no creo que sea por eso. Por cierto, entiendo que pasa por IF(V_TABLE = reg.TABLE_NAME) THEN pero ¿para qué está el else?

Comment: El else es para cuando el cursor ha terminado de recorrer una tabla y ha pasado a la siguiente, la variable coincida con el valor de reg.TABLE_NAME y así recoger las columnas de esa tabla. El ROWNUM está ahí para no tener que cargar todos los registros y que el descarte sea más rápido.

Comment: Por un lado, de ese modo se comprobaría que no hay registros en una tabla para cada una de las columnas de dicha tabla y la primera columna se escribiría siempre ya que no tiene la comprobación del count. Creo que deberías pasar la comprobación del count al else y usar una variable auxiliar que indique si dicha tabla tiene registros o no, que se inicializaría al mismo tiempo que v_table